# SQL - avoid duplicate data from external rest API

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure

I have an external rest API (https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/lendbook/usd), I want to insert data from there into my azure table but avoiding duplicate data. I know that the data itself sometimes has duplicate data, sometimes it does not, but I also doubt my query. Therefore, I'm looking for a solution to make sure that no duplicate data is pushed into my table even the API data is updated frequently.

Below is my code which use node-mssql to insert data, the core thing is the query:

```
insert(row: object): any {
    const sql = `
      IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.lendbook d WITH (HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE d.rate = @rate
               AND d.amount  = @amount
               AND d.period = @period
               AND d.timestamp = @timestamp
               AND d.type = @type
               AND d.frr = @frr
      )
      BEGIN
        INSERT dbo.lendbook
          (rate, amount, period, timestamp, type, frr)
        VALUES
          (@rate, @amount, @period, @timestamp, @type, @frr)
      END
    `;
    const ps = new mssql.PreparedStatement(this.db);
    ps.input('rate', mssql.Float);
    ps.input('amount', mssql.Float);
    ps.input('period', mssql.Int);
    ps.input('timestamp', mssql.DateTime);
    ps.input('type', mssql.NVarChar);
    ps.input('frr', mssql.NVarChar);

    ps.prepare(sql, (err: any) => {
      if (err) {
        LendbookService.LOGGER.error('MSSQL prepare error', err);
      }
      else {
        ps.execute(row, (err: any) => {
          if (err) {
            LendbookService.LOGGER.error('MSSQL execute error', err);
          }
          ps.unprepare((err: any) => {
            if (err) {
              LendbookService.LOGGER.error('MSSQL unprepare error', err);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
    return ps;
  }
```

This is the definition of my table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After hours of doing research and testing, I figured it out. The query below insert data from the rest API then filter the absolute duplicates (which have the same values in every column) before pushing into my table in the database. Hope it helps someone in the same situation.

```
const sql = `
      INSERT dbo.lendbook
        (rate, amount, period, timestamp, type, frr)
      VALUES
        (@rate, @amount, @period, @timestamp, @type, @frr)

      ;WITH cte
        AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rate, amount, period, timestamp, type, frr
          ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
          FROM dbo.lendbook)
      DELETE FROM cte
      WHERE  RN > 1;
    `;
```